# How does routing know so much?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am following a neat ruby on rails [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3SuV-A9bak&feature=bf_prev&list=UUS7Rh2UstIN09_eCjsIJ1LA) about routes. So I am wondering, how does routing know so much?

I have one controller called posts_controller, and a post model. In the routes.rb file, I added

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :posts
```

As far as I understood it, this automatically creates the appropriate routings for all the controller actions associated with a post. So far, I have only one method in my posts_controller:

```
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
def index

end
```

But strangely, when I execute

```
$ rake routes
```

it gives me all this:

```
    posts GET    /posts(.:format)          posts#index
          POST   /posts(.:format)          posts#create
 new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
     post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
          PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
```

How does the routing mechanism know so much without ever telling it that I want to able to create and update posts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using "resources" has nothing to do with the actions you have defined.  It simply creates all of the restful routes you could need in your controller.

As you can see it creates: index, create, new, edit, show, update, and destroy

It's actually unintelligent since it creates routes for actions which don't exist.

An example of how to limit it to only actions you need.

```
resources :posts, :only => [:show, :index]
```

Comment: Ah, that explains something. So is it unwise to use it? What would you use instead?

Comment: I don't mean to imply you shouldn't use it, just that it creates routes you may not need by default.  I've updated my code to show how you can limit to the actions you need.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Ruby on Rails guide, Resource Routing: the Rails Default](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default):

> Resource routing allows you to quickly declare all of the common routes for a given resourceful controller. Instead of declaring separate routes for your index, show, new, edit, create, update and destroy actions, a resourceful route declares them in a single line of code.

It is the Rails way of easily and quickly defining routes. It doesn't examine the methods in your controller.

Your understanding of how it works is correct. That being said if you don't want all the routes, and only want to have index, create, and update, you can choose to do this:

```
resources :posts, :only => [:index, :create, :update]
```